# Displaying Images differing in mobile view and in Desktop using Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am displaying in one row 6 columns as images in my website and I am using bootstrap 4 for diving colums, If I view the website in mobile means If the screen size(width) decreases I want to display images as 4 or 3 columns per row.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container shadow">
   <div class="row text-center">

    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <a href="category_details.php?id=Advertising Agencies">
            <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/558329813782376448/H2cb-84q_400x400.jpeg" height="70" width="70">
            <p class="text-para">image1</p>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <a href="category_details.php?id=Advocate">
      <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/558329813782376448/H2cb-84q_400x400.jpeg" height="70" width="70">
      <p class="text-para">image2</p>
    </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <a href="category_details.php?id=Agriculture">
      <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/558329813782376448/H2cb-84q_400x400.jpeg" height="70" width="70">
      <p class="text-para">image3</p>
    </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <a href="category_details.php?id=Architects">
      <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/558329813782376448/H2cb-84q_400x400.jpeg" height="70" width="70">
      <p class="text-para">image4</p>
    </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <a href="category_details.php?id=Astrologers">
      <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/558329813782376448/H2cb-84q_400x400.jpeg" height="70" width="70">
      <p class="text-para">image5</p>
    </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <a href="category_details.php?id=Automobiles">
      <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/558329813782376448/H2cb-84q_400x400.jpeg" height="70" width="70">
      <p class="text-para">image6</p>
    </a>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Here I am want to display images 4 or 3 images per row if the screen width decreases but that showing single image per row in mobile view, Please if anyone knows Please suggest me on the correct way.

Comment: guys anyone know please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for small screen you use

```
<div class="col-4 col-sm-2">
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container shadow">
   <div class="row text-center">

    <div class="col-4 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
        <a href="category_details.php?id=Advertising Agencies">
            <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/558329813782376448/H2cb-84q_400x400.jpeg" height="70" width="70">
            <p class="text-para">image1</p>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
      <a href="category_details.php?id=Advocate">
      <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/558329813782376448/H2cb-84q_400x400.jpeg" height="70" width="70">
      <p class="text-para">image2</p>
    </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
      <a href="category_details.php?id=Agriculture">
      <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/558329813782376448/H2cb-84q_400x400.jpeg" height="70" width="70">
      <p class="text-para">image3</p>
    </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
      <a href="category_details.php?id=Architects">
      <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/558329813782376448/H2cb-84q_400x400.jpeg" height="70" width="70">
      <p class="text-para">image4</p>
    </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
      <a href="category_details.php?id=Astrologers">
      <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/558329813782376448/H2cb-84q_400x400.jpeg" height="70" width="70">
      <p class="text-para">image5</p>
    </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4 col-sm-2 col-md-2">
      <a href="category_details.php?id=Automobiles">
      <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/558329813782376448/H2cb-84q_400x400.jpeg" height="70" width="70">
      <p class="text-para">image6</p>
    </a>
    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, bro,... awesome.